# Razor Pages - Access razor view binded variable value after ajax get request on server

Tags: javascript, c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to bind this variable on view so i don't need to send it through ajax call, not sure if that is possible but following the logic it looks like it would be.

```
    <script>

    $(function ()
    {
        GetStocksByUAP();
    });

    function GetStocksByUAP() {

        @{
            Model.Sector = "UAP1";
        }

        $.get('/dashboard/Index?handler=StocksBySector', function (response) {

                swal('OK', 'Dados carregados', 'success');
                console.log(response);



            });
    }

</script>
```

cs file

```
 [BindProperty]
    public string Sector { get; set; }


    public IndexModel(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetStocksBySectorAsync()
    {
        IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        var result = await con.QueryAsync<DashboardViewModel>("GetStocksByUAP", new { UAP = Sector });

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

To summit up, I'm trying to use the string Sector declared on the page and access it's value binded on the view after ajax get request on server. Not sure if this is possible though

Comment: can you state the actual question please?

Comment: edited at the end, should be more clear what i 'm trying to achieve

Comment: Why are you setting the value of a model property in the view? Your workflow looks flawed to me.

Comment: I was trying to test if i could use a server model to bind a value and use it on server after ajax request. It's seem it is not possible so i just used javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process a value in a handler that gets called by an AJAX request using the `GET` method, you need to pass the value to the handler. You can do that as a query string value or as a route data value, but either way, it must be passed in the URL.

If you want to bind the value to a PageModel property, you must specify `SupportsGet = true` in the `BindProperty` attribute:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public string Sector { get; set; }
```

See more about how model binding works in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-data-from-get-requests